# how to dump output of a perl script on linux into a log file with file name as timestamp

Tags: linux, perl, logging

I have a perl script example.pl that I run on linux box. I need to capture the output from the execution of the perl script and timestamp its name. I know the output redirection method but I am looking for a way to do it from the script example.pl itself (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **redirect** output and error streams using [`Typeglobs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) or you can do the following.

```
#!/bin/perl 

open(STDOUT, '>',time.".out") or die $!; #the time function gives you the timestamp
open(STDERR, '>',time.".err") or die $!;
print "output"; #goes to <timestamp>.out
warn "error";   #goes to <timestamp>.err
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to redirect the STDOUT to a file. Just do this at the beginning of the script:

```
open STDOUT, '>', "my_stdout_file.txt";
```

And this is a function that returns a file name with a timestamp:

```
sub generate_timestamp_filename {
    my $tstamp = sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", 
                                $now[5]+1900, 
                                $now[4]+1, 
                                $now[3],
                                $now[2],      
                                $now[1],   
                                $now[0] );

    return "my_prefix_$tstamp.txt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quickest way to do this:

```
 open(STDOUT, ">myfile") or die $!;
 print "Hello world"; #now goes to myfile

 open(STDERR, ">hisfile") or die $!;
 warn "Error here"; #and that's in hisfile
```

The other alternative is to use `select`:

```
open(my $FILE, ">stdout") or die $!;
my $old = select($FILE);

# Done capturing output
select $old;
```

Comment: `select` will fail if someone uses `STDOUT` directly and won't be inherited by child processes, but it's easy to restore.